# JSON: Add a unique key iterator for every json array object

Tags: json, jq

Im trying to achieve the following transformation for a big json file. How do I do it using jq or any command line tools.

Input

```
    {
        "client": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
        "instance_id": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
        "fstype": "ext4",
        "device": "nvme0n1p1"
    },
    {
        "client": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
        "instance_id": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
        "fstype": "ext4",
        "device": "nvme0n1p1"
    }
```

Output

```
"1": {
      "client": "i-00112fc0b535a9d2e",
      "instance_id": "i-00112fc0b535a9d2e",
      "fstype": "ext4",
      "device": "nvme0n1p1"
   },
"2": {
      "client": "i-0876600d6d3d72477",
      "instance_id": "i-0876600d6d3d72477",
      "fstype": "ext4",
      "device": "nvme0n1p1"
   }
```

Comment: 1. Please fix the JSON input, and clarify whether or not you want valid JSON output.  2. How big is "big"?  Will the input fit into memory?  (You can check that by running `jq empty FILE.json')

Answer (score 2):

Neither the input sample nor your desired output is valid JSON. Arrays need surrounding brackets `[..., ...]`, and objects need surrounding curly braces `{"...": ..., "...": ...}`.

Assuming your input and output documents are supposed to be an array and and an object, respectively, and their difference in the values of `.client` and `.instance_id` are just a mistake while composing this question, it looks like all you need is a conversion to and from an array of "entries" using `to_entries` and `from_entries`, and a `map` in between to convert the keys to strings. As this pattern is so common, a special builtin `with_entries` does the first and last conversion and the mapping at once: `with_entries`. The middle conversion can be achieved with `tostring` or `@text`, or even string interpolation `"\(...)"`:

```json
[
  {
    "client": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
    "instance_id": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "device": "nvme0n1p1"
  },
  {
    "client": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
    "instance_id": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "device": "nvme0n1p1"
  }
]
```

```bash
jq 'with_entries(.key |= tostring)'
```

```json
{
  "0": {
    "client": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
    "instance_id": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "device": "nvme0n1p1"
  },
  "1": {
    "client": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
    "instance_id": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "device": "nvme0n1p1"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UnAyEcPBHdt)

If you want some (numeric) pre-processing of the key numbers, do it inside the mapping and before the string conversion, e.g.

```bash
jq 'with_entries(.key |= (. + 1 | tostring))'
```

```json
{
  "1": {
    "client": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
    "instance_id": "i-0816dfac36b036002",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "device": "nvme0n1p1"
  },
  "2": {
    "client": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
    "instance_id": "i-09ae6f92cda7fca83",
    "fstype": "ext4",
    "device": "nvme0n1p1"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1mv6Xi9G-Xi)